# How to pass accessToken to Axios interceptor without Redux

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, server-side-rendering, interceptor

I am trying to authorize a Next app using the existing Nodejs backend using a manual JWT strategy.

My backend issues an access token, and I'm trying to sign each request with `accessToken` using `axios.interceptor` where I set `Bearer ${token}`

```
// utils/axios.ts

const axiosPrivate = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL,
  timeout: 1000,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
});

axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
  (config: AxiosRequestConfig): AxiosRequestConfig => {
    if (config.headers === undefined) {
      config.headers = {};
    }

    // no way to access sessionStorage or document.cookies

    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${accessToken}`

    return config;
  }
);

export { axiosPrivate }
```

My question is if there is some way to grab access token **without Redux**?

I want it in the interceptor because it will let me do SSR like that:

```
// pages/dashboard.tsx

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {

  const res = await axiosPrivate.get('/dashboard'); // request already signed

  return {
    props: {
      dashboard: res.data,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: How about to use the localStorage on client (didn't get context of Redux - as don't see any related code). My understanding is that you keep token on server side - still you need to somehow map the token to current user (browser). Where did you store that info?

Comment: there is no access to client data from `getServerSideProps` though I can reach token from `context.req.headers.cookie`. The thing is I don't really want to add accessToken for every page route :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the accessToken in the params for the axios request.

```
<code>await axiosPrivate.get('/dashboard', {
  params: {
    accessToken
  }
});
</code>
```

Comment: OP is clearly using a request header, not query params.